# Cambiar color texto celda bootstrap table en función del contenido

Tags: java, bootstrap, bootstrap-table

tengo una tabla bootstrap con la siguiente pinta:

```html
<table id="tableDashboardGrid"
 class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
 data-pagination="true" data-toggle="table" data-url="/dashboardGrid"
 data-page-list="[5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200]" data-search="true"
 data-toolbar="#toolbar">
 <thead>
  <tr>
<!--   <th data-checkbox="true"></th> -->
   <th data-field="tableName" data-sortable="true" data-align="center" data-editable="false" th:text="#{dashboard.columns.tableName}"/>
   <th data-field="timestamp" data-sortable="true" data-formatter="hourFormatter" data-align="center" data-editable="false" th:text="#{dashboard.columns.timestamp}"/>
   <th data-field="registries" data-sortable="true" data-align="center" data-editable="false" th:text="#{dashboard.columns.registries}"/>
   <th data-field="nonZeroRegistries" data-sortable="true"
data-align="center" data-editable="false" th:text="#{dashboard.columns.nonZeroRegistries}"/>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true" data-align="center" data-editable="false" th:text="#{dashboard.columns.state}"/>
   <th data-field="attempts" data-sortable="true" data-align="center" data-editable="false" th:text="#{dashboard.columns.attemps}"/>
   <th data-formatter="actionsFormatter" data-events="editDashboardEvents" th:text="#{actions}"/>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
```

No tiene tbody, por lo que se monta en función de los registros que devuelve la petición a la url indicada en la cabecera de la tabla. El método java sería el siguiente:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboardGrid", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> adminDashboard(Model model) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String listCinJsonString = "";

    List<ControlInputDTO> listCins = new ArrayList<ControlInputDTO>();
    listCins = (List<ControlInputDTO>) cinService.findAll();

    try {
        listCinJsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(listCins);

    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(listCinJsonString, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Mi pregunta es, habiendo montado la tabla de esta forma (me lo encontré así al heredar el desarrollo), es posible pintar los textos de una determinada columna (todos menos el de la cabecera) de un color determinado en función del contenido de dicha columna? Pretendo que la columna 'state' se pinte de color verde si el estado es 'OK', amarillo si es 'Warning', rojo si es 'Error' etc...

Si no se puede, cuál podría ser la alternativa mejor?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero encontré otra más sencilla. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré una solución muy sencilla, proporcionada también por la librería bootstrap-table. Es la siguiente:

En la fila que se quiere pintar en función de algo, añadir la propiedad ***data-cell-style***, indicando un método js con el que cambiar esta propiedad

```html
<th data-field="state" data-sortable="true" data-cell-style="cellStyle" data-align="center" data-editable="false" th:text="#{dashboard.columns.state}"/>
```

Después, en el método js, implementaríamos lo siguiente:

```js
function cellStyle (value, row, index) {
 switch (value) {
  case 'INITIAL':
   return {
    classes: 'text-dark'
   }
   break;
  case 'OK':
   return {
    classes: 'text-warning'
   }
   break;
  case 'SAVED':
   return {
    classes: 'text-success'
   }
   break;
 }
}
```

Con eso se soluciona.

Comment: Solo como observación, `data-cell-style` no es una propiedad de Bootstrap. Estás utilizando una librería adicional de tablas, la cual no pertenece a BS.

Comment: Exactamente, mi comentario era pensando que no usabas ningún tipo de librería externa. Por favor pon la etiqueta de la librería que uses en la pregunta ya que esta respuesta no respondería a tu pregunta como tal de [java] y [bootstrap]

Comment: He añadido la etiqueta bootstrap-table como etiqueta. Creía que no era necesario añadirla. Gracias a ambos